# How to create different Admin Roles in Strapi

Tags: node.js, reactjs, strapi

I want to give separate permission roles to the users that can access the Strapi Admin. I know that this feature is currently in development. And I found that a few years ago, a tutorial was posted in Strapi to try to help temporarily solve this problem with a Front-End solution.

https://strapi.io/blog/admin-permissions

Is it still possible to implement this solution in Strapi 3.x?

I believe it was meant to be used in the alpha version of Strapi. In the tutorial, they modify the User model, but now, to be able to access Strapi Admin, it has to be an Admin user.

I tried to follow the instructions, creating the admin and plugins folder (and replicating the modifications in the plugin folder to the extension folder, just in case), but without modifying the Admin model I don't think it will be of any use.

There's also another solution, the BunAdmin: https://github.com/bunred/bunadmin-plugin-strapi-user, that some people said it could be used. But BunAdmin uses the GraphQl and we use Mongo on Strapi.

I'm about to try using the React-Admin: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/

Has anyone managed to create different admin roles using the latest version of Strapi with MongoDB?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: I tried using the React Admin with [Simple REST Data Provider for React Admin - Strapi](https://github.com/nazirov91/ra-strapi-rest), but we customized all of our GET requests, so this Data Provider doesn't work for us. I had to modify our requests and create a custom Data Provider. Not the ideal solution, but it is viable with React Admin+Data Provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On July 13, this feature was released in Strapi 3.1 version.

https://strapi.io/blog/announcing-3.1-role-based-access-control